# How to change the class of a HTML <div> using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm modifying a HTML file using Python and BeautifulSoup,and I can change the content of headers,but I couldn't find a way to change the class of a div. My goal is to turn

```
<div id="div1" class="blue_titles">test</div>
```

into:
    `<div id="div1" class="green_titles">test</div>`

I looked up and down the docs,but to no avail. It's probably right on my face,but I can't find it.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply assign the new value to the key `class`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<div id="div1" class="blue_titles">test</div>""", "lxml")
soup.find("div")['class'] = "green_titles"

soup
# <html><body><div class="green_titles" id="div1">test</div></body></html>
```